# Very easy integration clarification

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Here is a question that I have, probably because my fundamentals are very shaky.

Suppose $A(x,y,\lambda): \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\displaystyle \frac{\partial A}{\partial \lambda} = c \in \mathbb{R}$. Upon integrating both sides by $\lambda$, we obtain $A(x,y,\lambda) = c\lambda + c_0(x,y)$, where $c_0(x,y) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

So the question is.... **How? In what sense are we integrating?**

I'm interpreting the integration by $\lambda$ as $\displaystyle \int \text{d} A(x,y,\lambda) = \int c ~\text{d} \lambda$. But how do we reach this form? $\displaystyle c = \frac{\partial A}{\partial \lambda} \approx \frac{\text{d}A}{\text{d} \lambda}$ (I know this isn't valid so please don't be upset), so, uh $\displaystyle \int \text{d} A = \int c ~\text{d} \lambda$?

Comment: It might be better to think of "anti partial derivatives" rather than integrals in this situation.

Comment: @halrankard2 in that case, am I right to think that you can't deduce uniquely the form $A = c \lambda + c_0$? (As fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't extend to partial derivatives; I don't even know how $\int \partial x$ is even defined....)

Comment: No your answer is correct, the issue is trying to interpret it as some kind of integral in the geometric sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fixed $x$ and $y$ define $f(\lambda)=A(x,y,\lambda)$. The equation we are solving is just the equation $\frac d {d\lambda} f(\lambda)=c$. The solution is $f(\lambda)=c\lambda+c_0$ where $c_0$ is a constant. But if we want to vary $x$ and $y$ now there is no reason why you should get the same constant $c_0$ every time. So $c_0$ actually depends on $x$ and $y$ and we call it $c_0(x,y)$.